# Calling a js function without data attributes

Tags: javascript, attributes

I am using a template which included a js function for sliding in off screen divs.
Normal usage is:

```
<button type="button" data-slide="slide" data-target="#my-panel"> My Panel</button>
```

or

```
<a href"#" data-slide="slide" data-target="#my-panel">My Panel</a>
```

I am also using a 3rd party light box script which allows me to call other functions when it closes. I have used this to call my own scripts like this `onBoxEnd(hvrOn(5))`.

My question is how do I write for something like the onBoxEnd(?) with a function that is normally activated with a click with data attributes? I have tried permutations of `onBoxEnd(data-slide="slide" data-target="#my-panel")` and naming the function and to try and call it like `onBoxEnd(pageslide(#my-panel))` but nothing I'm doing works. Also the creator of the light box code says he is unable to assist in this matter.

Here is the first portion of the sliding div panel code ( I added the name pageslide):

```
     $(function pageslide() {        
    $('[data-slide="slide"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $this.attr('data-target');
    var $target = $(target);
    if ($('.slide-panel-parent').children().is('.open')) {
        $('.open').not(target).removeClass('open');
        $('.active-slide-btn').not(this).removeClass('active-slide-btn');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-slide-btn');
        $(target).toggleClass('open');
        $('html').removeClass('slide-active');
```

I have not been able to locate any basic info on this -only how to use data attributes to a function and I couldn't see how to reverse that - so a useable solution or even a pointer towards where to study up on this would be very much  appreciated.

Comment: You can't just put a selector directly into the arguments of a function. The selector is a string, so it has to be in quotes. And you need to call `$( )` to select the elements using it. So it shoul be something like `onBoxEnd($("[data-slide=slide][data-target='#my-panel']"))`. I'm not writing an answer because I really don't understand the question.

Comment: Is there also a "normal usage" way on the page? Then you could use jquery's .trigger() function to simulate a click on an actual DOM element in your page that has the data-attributes included:
`$('[data-slide="slide"]').trigger("click")`

Comment: @Barmar - While your suggestion did not work your attempt seems to fit exactly what I am asking ;) I'm pretty sure that how you might write the call to the sliding div function from inside another script would be another way of phrasing this and a correct solution.

Comment: @illuminaut - The first two examples - button and anchor - are normal usage and work as expected. I want to open a specific panel from within a lightbox modal which is technically disconnected from the page that opens it. However, the code that operates the lightbox can trigger a call 'through' that page after the modal close and before the lightbox code ends.

Comment: @illuminaut - Your suggestion of using the jQuery .trigger seems to be useful solution. I'd mark that as the accepted answer but I don't see how to do that. I guess you didn't propose it as a solution.